# Decoding base64 php file

Tags: php, base64

I currently have an encoded footer file for a wordpress file I want to decode, because the theme author has put in some 'interesting' links.  Don't get me wrong, I'm very happy to link back to the author, but gambling sites aren't really what I want!

The file is this-

```
<?php $o="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";eval(base64_decode("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"));return;?>
```

Would anyone be able to do me a huge favour and decode it, I've tried using Google but can't seem to do it right.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php ?

Comment: This is not as simple as you think, there are multiple levels of encoding in here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That whole mass of a thing translates into this:

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/bottom.php'); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer">
<div class="fmenu">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a></li>
 <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&depth=1&title_li='); ?>
</ul>
</div>  

<span class="left">  Designed  by <a href="http://www.web2feel.com" target="_blank"> web2feel.com </a>  </span>
<span class="right"> Coded  by <a href="http://www.localmatch.com/" target="_blank">Local Dating</a>, <a href="http://www.onlinedatingresource.com/" target="_blank">Dating Tips</a>,<a href="http://www.millionaireflirt.com/" target="_blank">Sugar Daddies</a>  </span>

</div>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Clean it up and replace it with that whole crazy thing.

For those who are interested, here's an intermediate code I used to get it:

```
<pre>
<?php 
$o="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";

$l=base64_decode($o);
$ll=0;
$lll=0;
$llll=0;
$lllll=3;
$llllll=(ord($l[1])<<8)+ord($l[2]);
$lllllll=0;
$llllllll="";
$lllllllll=16;

for(;$lllll<strlen($l);) {
    if($lllllllll==0) { 
        $llllll = ord($l[$lllll++]) << 8;
        $llllll += ord($l[$lllll++]);
        $lllllllll=16;
    }

    if($llllll&0x8000) {
        $lll = ord($l[$lllll++])<<4;
        $lll += ord($l[$lllll])>>4;
        if($lll) {
            $ll = (ord($l[$lllll++])&0x0f) + 3;
            for($llll=0; $llll<$ll; $llll++)
                $llllllll[$lllllll+$llll] = $llllllll[$lllllll-$lll+$llll];

            $lllllll += $ll;
        } else {
            $ll = ord($l[$lllll++]) << 8;
            $ll += ord($l[$lllll++]) + 16;

            for($llll=0; $llll<$ll; $llllllll[$lllllll+$llll++] = ord($l[$lllll]));
                $lllll++;

            $lllllll += $ll;
        }
    } else
        $llllllll[$lllllll++] = ord($l[$lllll++]);

    $llllll <<= 1;
    $lllllllll--;
}

$lllll=0;
$llllllllll="";
for(;$lllll<$lllllll;) { 
    $llllllllll .= chr($llllllll[$lllll++]^0x07);
}

echo htmlentities($llllllllll);
```

Comment: What did you do with the missing characters in the encoded string?

Comment: They are generated using ord() and chr(), the missing strings are the starting `?>` and ending `<?` :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Very impressive!

Comment: Hi, @LiraNuna, how did you manage to decode this? I have a similar one from the same author. :\ http://pastebin.com/xqZqRhum

Answer (score 1):

The length of the string is invalid.

Anyway, if you remove a couple characters at the end, you'll get something like this using `base64_decode($o);` :

```
<?php
$lll=0;
eval(base64_decode("JGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsPSdiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlJzs="));
$ll=0;
eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbGw9J29yZCc7"));
$llll=0;
$lllll=3;
eval($lllllllllll("JGw9JGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsKCRvKTs="));
$lllllll=0;
$llllll=($llllllllll($l[1])<<8)+$llllllllll($l[2]);
eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGw9J3N0cmxlbic7"));
$lllllllll=16;
$llllllll="";
for(;
$lllll<$lllllllllllll($l);
){if($lllllllll==0){$llllll=($llllllllll($l[$lllll++])<<8);
$llllll+=$llllllllll($l[$lllll++]);
$lllllllll=16;
}if($llllll&0x8000){$lll=($llllllllll($l[$lllll++])<<4);
$lll+=($llllllllll($l[$lllll])>>4);
if($lll){$ll=($llllllllll($l[$lllll++])&0x0f)+3;
for($llll=0;
$llll<$ll;
$llll++)$llllllll[$lllllll+$llll]=$llllllll[$lllllll-$lll+$llll];
$lllllll+=$ll;
}else{$ll=($llllllllll($l[$lllll++])<<8);
$ll+=$llllllllll($l[$lllll++])+16;
for($llll=0;
$llll<$ll;
$llllllll[$lllllll+$llll++]=$llllllllll($l[$lllll]));
$lllll++;
$lllllll+=$ll;
}}else$llllllll[$lllllll++]=$llllllllll($l[$lllll++]);
$llllll<<=1;
$lllllllll--;
}eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbD0nY2hyJzs="));
$lllll=0;
eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbD0iPyIuJGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbCg2Mik7"));
$llllllllll="";
for(;
$lllll<$lllllll;
){$llllllllll.=$llllllllllll($llllllll[$lllll++]^0x07);
}eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbC49JGxsbGxsbGxsbGwuJGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbCg2MCkuIj8iOw=="));
eval($lllllllll)
?>
```

Just six characters are missing here